# Correct approach to secure the back end service - oAuth

Tags: java, web-services, security, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a oAuth service (I'm thinking so. It might not be exactly the same.) to open one of our back end API to a Merchants.

basically users can purchase goods from Merchant's E-Commerce website and can use our payment gateway to
do the payment.

we have registration system for merchants and users and we are issuing a ID(publically available alpha numeric ) to them.

My plan is for oAuth service.

```
   1) First merchant sends above mentioned id to our oAuth server.
   2) Then oAuth server sending token, refresh token and expiry time as response.
   3) Then merchant sends that token with other required information such as amount again to oAuth server to open our payment gateway web interface.
   4) user use that interface to provide his ID and pin to confirm the transactions.
   5) Then from over oAuth server we call our back end RESTFull service to do the actual transaction (Merchant account receive money and customer account will debited)
   6) After completion of transaction we redirect user again to merchant's website.
```

*All the communications are done via `https` channel.

I'm in doubt for

```
    1) Whether  my approach is correct to secure the above given flow.
    2) Do I really need a tokens here or only ID is enough? If I only used ID what I'm going to missing here.
    3) Is there any possibility that some one can cheat the process.
```

Expecting you advices on this.

Answer (score 1):

Does yours and the merchant site have correlated user-ids? Some points to note based on a similar implementation we have done.

1. You definitely need a token.
2. IMO, you should tag the token to an user-id which means that the merchant should send the user-id along in the initial request.
3. I do not see why you need to send the expiry time back to the merchant app. Just the token would suffice. You should have a service that expires used tokens.
4. Consider encrypting the tokens in some fashion.

Comment: Does yours and the merchant site have correlated user-ids? yes at registration process we issue a ID.  Do you think Is there any possibility that some one can cheat the process ?

Comment: Nothing is fully secure on the internet, IMHO :). That said, an encrypted token exchange mechanism over https is reasonably ok. You should be attaching the tokens to users.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like an OAuth. You kind of mix merchants and users treating both as end-users. In OAuth the user is the key player and clients (merchants) are only acting on behalf of the user after the user provides consent.

You do not need OAuth to authorize merchants to access your APIs (just use client-id and client-secret for that), you need OAuth to authorize merchants to access your APIs **on behalf of the user**.

If you would try to use OAuth protocol for your purpose, a merchant would be a client-application and it would need to register (once) and get a client-id and likely a client-secret form your payment system. No tokens are issued for a client (merchant) alone.

Client then should ask a user (buyer) to authorize access to the payment service on behalf of him. This is where token is issued if user logs in and provides consent. Tokens are normally bound to client+user.

But OAuth protocol is not sufficient at this step for your case: OAuth supports scopes for a user's consent, but you need a consent for a payment - at least the amount but probably also some other info. Maybe you could use extra params to deliver that info.

After the user consent, client (merchant) gets a token and may invoke your payment system on behalf of the user. Maybe merchant could use the token to ask for payment details once again.

Comment: You have understood my problem and replied well. I understood your approach to use oauth. But I can't go with that so could you kindly suggest me a way to secure the api align with my above steps.